# Finding the coefficient x^12 of a generating function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Hi so I am trying to find the coefficient (x)^(12) in $(1-x^5)^3$·(1-x)^(-3)

I know this becomes $(1-3x^5$+3x^(10))·$(1+3C1x+4C2x^2+....)$

Then =14C2-3·8C6+3·1

I am abit confursed where the8C6 and 3·1 come from.

Thanks in advance,

Jordan

Comment: There is a lacking term in your first factor: you should have $(1-3x^5+3x^{10}-x^{15})$.Now I dont understand your second factor...

Comment: For your second factor, derive twice the quotient $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+...$, you will obtain $f"(x)=\dfrac{2}{(1-x)^3}=2+6 x+12x^2+...$ (dont forget to divide by 2 the result). Now to obtain the coefficient of $x^{12}$, you need to associate for example $3x^{10}$ in the first factor with 6x^2 in the second parenthesis, etc...